# Getting error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, sftp

Trying to run a `sftp` client using `nodejs` but getting a wired error. The error is

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

```
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();
const process = require('process');

const config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '1026',
    username: 'Nav****',
    password: '*******'
}



sftp.connect(config)


const list = ()=>{
    sftp.connect(config).then(() => {
           return sftp.list('../send_backend');
    }).then((data) => {
            console.log(data, 'the data info');
    }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err, 'catch error');
    })
}
console.log("=======================================");

console.log("received data =>" + list());
```

Answer (score 0):

What is "sftp.connect(config)" doing outside the list. As I can see you are neither using resolve nor the rejected case. That is causing the issue. So you should either handle the exception or remove that code!

In case you want to handle it

```
sftp.connect(config)
  .then(()=>{//do something here})
  .catch((exception)=>{ console.log(exception) // do something else })
```

As discussed in comments, You may use this:

```
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();
const process = require('process');
const config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '1026',
    username: 'Nav****',
    password: '*******'
}
sftp.connect(config)
  .then(()=>{
    // what you want to do after you make connection goes here
  })
  .catch((exception)=>{ 
       console.log(exception) // do something else
   })
```

Comment: so how can i handle the exception here?

Comment: first things first why do you even need that bit there!

Comment: the problem is that i want a sftp client and i saw this snippet of code somewhere so i just copied and paste.....i dont know what exactly happening here.

Comment: Entire part have been copied.

Comment: Where can i find that?